# jQuery DatePicker Bug?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I'm using jQuery DatePicker and it shows wrong date for November, 2009.

You can see this in my sample page.

http://project-base-23.codepremise.com/door/test_calendar

Is this a known bug? How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Sam

Comment: November this year has two '1'.

Comment: naah, just see a single '1'.. the way I see it, It starts on a sunday, and goes on upto 3oth on a Monday. The next block (Tue) is a '1', but belongs to December.

Comment: Hi,
Here's a screen capture of the problem.

http://project-base-23.codepremise.com/images/capture.png

Don't you see the same problem?

Comment: That is odd.
I do not get this problem. It correctly shows Monday as the 2nd on mine.

Is this the jQuery UI datepicker you are using? Can you post the init code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is daylight savings.  Essentially, because of the "fall back" of one hour, November 1st has 25 hours.  The bug is resolved in the most recent version of datepicker: http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/scripts/jquery.datePicker.js.

That's what it does...

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a problem with November, 2009. Apparently this problem was also visible in November, 2008 except it was with the 2nd of November, not the 1st. I'm dealing with the EXACT same issue. I found two suggestions elsewhere that I am going to try. They may be helpful to you as well:

I found this advice at http://www.nabble.com/bug-in-date-display-in-jquery-date-picker-td20341195s27240.html from a posting in 2008!
"
The bug is fixed by replacing line 1308 with:

printDate.setDate(printDate.getDate() + 1);

instead of the UTC version.  Haven't done any regression testing, but
it seems to work. 
"
The other suggestion was to upgrade the version which also makes a lot of sense.

Does anyone know if this is the way to go?

Answer (score 1):

We had the same problem. Not only were there two Nov 1, 2009, but each Monday following the first Sunday of November in any year was a duplicate date. As [Dawn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/151310/dawn) suggested, changing this line of code

```
printDate.setUTCDate(printDate.getUTCDate() + 1);
```

to this

```
printDate.setDate(printDate.getDate() + 1);
```

seems to have solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Date isn't wrong, you just have date format mm/dd/Y, so November 18th 2009 is 11/18/2009.

Or have I misunderstood your question? :)

Comment: In November, 2009, There are two '1' (Sunday and Monday).

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me. You do realize that the calendar has Sunday set as the first day, right? Because that shifts the "look" of the calendar by one day.

If there is some other error, please explain a bit deeper what you're getting/expecting.

Comment: I am sorry that my question was not clear. In November this year, there are two '1'.